# Defining a Macro for a property that works with different objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to define a macro for a setting a property such as backgroundColor for multiple objects?

For example:

```
#define RedColor [UIColor redColor]
#define BackgroundColor(color) [[self class] setBackgroundColor:Color(color)]
```

So that I could use it in cases like:

```
[myLabel BackgroundColor(RedColor)];
[myButton BackgroundColor(RedColor)];
```

Comment: What's wrong with `[myLabel setBackgroundColor:RedColor]` and `[myButton setBackgroundColor:RedColor]`?

Comment: also check UIAppearance protocol https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html . May be it provides something similar to what you need

Comment: @ahruss this is more of a simplified example but I'm meaning to use something like this for more verbose properties that require multiple inputs (such as my own-defined ones), so my code looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: I think we're going to need some more explanation of what you want, then. The answer to the question you've asked is yes, and it's trivial to do something like `#define BackgroundColor(color) setBackgroundColor:color`, but I'm assuming that's not what you're looking for, as it doesn't do anything other than obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not recommend you to do it, the following code works for me:

```
#define BackgroundColor(color, some_view) [some_view setBackgroundColor:color]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach that I use:

1. Create a header file `Colors.h`.
2. Import this header file in your `pch`file so it will be imported in all of your header files.
3. In `Colors.h` insert the following:

   //RGB color macro
   `#define RGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
   colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
   green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
   blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]`

   //RGB color macro with alpha
   `#define RGBA(rgbValue,a) [UIColor \
   colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
   green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
   blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:a]`

   // Color swatch
   `#define COLOR_SWATCH_WHITE      RGB(0xFFFFFF)`
   `#define COLOR_SWATCH_BLACK      RGB(0x000000)`

   // Constants
   `#define COLOR_BUTTON_TEXT        COLOR_SWATCH_BLACK`
   `#define COLOR_BUTTON_BACKGROUND  COLOR_SWATCH_WHITE`
4. Example of setting a color:
   `[myLabel setTextColor:COLOR_BUTTON_TEXT];`
5. I think it's a good idea to have this approach with a 'Color swatch' since mostly every application has a set of a few colors used throught the app.